# Spivak's Calculus Chapter 28-1 (Fields)

Tags: finite-fields, ordered-fields

[Question in Textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krEhX.png)

The question defines a set F and then defines the operations on F through a table. In this chapter, Spivak outlines the properties that operators on a field must have. In the example in textbook he says that that the verifications of the conditions are simple, case by case checks. However, would that not be extremely long and tedious going through every case for every element in set F? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: It only has three elements.  That's not many things to check.  You should do it for the experience and no, I do not think that is extremely long and although it is tedious it is acceptably tedious.

Comment: The descriptions of the rules are given.  As $a +0=a$ and $0 \le a < 3$ then $0+a = a+0 = a$ so that proves an additive identity. Continue that way.  Put it in your own words.  $m+n=n+m$ and so $m+n-3k = n+m-3k$ so this rule of addition is commutative so to find if there are additive inverse it's enough to just note $0+0=0; 1+2=0; $ and .... that's all.  And so on.

Comment: the show addition is commutative you only have to check three things, same with multiplication. To show an additive identity exist is three things and to show multiplicative is to check two things.  The show inverse are three and two things.  That's not many.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to show addition is commutative for each of the possible combinations you have the elements in the set? Sorry if that doesn't make sense, maybe I'm understanding this wrong

Comment: There's only three elements so there are only three pairs to check!  That is a *VERY* small number.  Does $1 + 0 = 0+1$. Yes.  Does $2+0=0+2$.  Yes.  Does $1+2=2+1$. Yes.  That's it we are done and you checked them *all*.  But because addition on the set is defined by addition on the integers (and just subtract a multiple of $3$ if you go over) the addition on the set is commutative because addition on the intervals is.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you know that this field happens to be the field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ (you don't need to know what that means), then maybe you can use the general argument that $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (again, don't need to know what that means) is a field.

However, I don't think the axioms are as hard to verify as you might think they are. For instance, the existence of additive identity means that one of the columns in the addition table looks the same as the column listing the elements being added. The existence of additive inverses is the same as saying that every column in the addition table has a $0$ in it. Commutativity means that flipping the multiplication table along the diagonal gives the same table. So, this is quicker to manually verify than you might think. Does that help?

Comment: Yes that actually does. There was another thing I was confused about. In an he showed earlier show property (1, commutativity) in another set, he says to check the 8 equations in which a,b,c = 0 or 1 in a set which contains {0,1}. How exactly does that work?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure what your sentence means and what your question is

Answer (score 0):

The Field is only !$3$! elements.  It is very easy and short to check everything.

Axiom 1:  Addition is commutative.  If $a = b$ then $a+b= a+a=b+a$ so we only have to check if $a\ne b$ and there are only three such pairs.  $0 + 1 = 1=1+0; 0+2=2=2+0; 1+2=0=2+1$.  That's it.  We checked them all.

Axiom 2: Addition is associative.  The check $(a+b) + c = a+(b+c)$ is $27$ cases of $a,b,c$ but we can cut that down with commons sense. If $a,b$ or $c=0$ then $(a+b) + 0 = a+b = a +(b+0)$ and $(a+0)+c= a+c = a+(0+c)$ and $(0+b) +c = b+c = 0 + (b+c)$. (See axiom 3).  If none of $a,b,c=0$ then that is only $8$ cases but still we must have two of them equal or three of the equal and as addition is commutative:

$(a+a) + a = a+(a+a)$ and $(a+a)+b=a+(a+b)$ can be checked with $4$ cases.  And $(a+b) +a= a+(a+b)=a+(b+a)$.  And $(b+a)+a=(a+b)+a=a+(a+b)=(a+a) + b=b+(a+a)$.  so that associativity.

Axiom 3: $0+a = a+0= a$.  Just three things to check.  $0+0=0;1+0=1;2+0=0$ that's it we checked them *ALL*.

Axiom 4: even element has an additive inverse.  Only three to check.  $0+0=0$ so $0$ has an inverse.  $1+2 = 0$ so $1$ has an inverse. $2+1=0$ so $2$ has inverse.

Multiplication axioms are similar.

that was *not* a lot to do.

Showing no order can exist is figure: $0 = 1 + 1 + 1$  If $1 > 0$ then $1+1 > 0+1$ and $1+1+1 > 0+1+1$ and if $1< 0$ .... well same thing.

Comment: Thanks this makes it very clear. It was difficult to understand from the textbook for me.